# Hamiltonian system with double integration

Tags: calculus, optimal-control

I have an Hamiltonian system with double integrals so, it is not possible to solve this kind of system with standard optimal control approach.
I suppose that it is necessary to focus on calculus of variation.
I would really appreciate if you have any suggestions (textbook, paper etc.) in order to solve this kind of system.